# Show that $y_2(t)=e^{-t^2/2}\int_0^te^{s^2/2}ds$ is a solution of $y"+ty'+y=0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Show that

> $$y_2(t)=e^{-t^2/2}\int_0^te^{s^2/2}ds $$ is a solution of
>
> $$ y''+ty'+y=0 $$

I seem to be making a mistake somewhere in my calculations, and I was hoping someone could tell me where exactly I am making the mistake:

$$y_2(t)=e^{-t^2/2}\int_0^te^{s^2/2}ds$$

$$y_2'(t)=e^{-t^2/2}(\int_0^te^{s^2/2}ds)'+(e^{-t^2/2})'\int_0^te^{s^2/2}ds$$
$$=e^{-t^2/2}(e^{t^2/2}-e^0)+(-te^{-t^2/2})\int_0^te^{s^2/2}ds$$
$$=e^{-t^2/2}(e^{t^2/2}-1)+(-te^{-t^2/2})\int_0^te^{s^2/2}ds$$
$$=1-e^{-t^2/2}+(-te^{-t^2/2})\int_0^te^{s^2/2}ds$$

$$y''_2(t)=0-(e^{-t^2/2})'+(-te^{-t^2/2})(\int_0^te^{s^2/2}ds)'+(\int_0^te^{s^2/2}ds)(-te^{-t^2/2})'$$
$$y''_2(t)=te^{-t^2/2}+(-te^{-t^2/2})(e^{t^2/2}-e^{0})+(t^2-1)(e^{-t^2/2})\int_0^te^{s^2/2}ds$$
$$y''_2(t)=te^{-t^2/2}+(-te^{-t^2/2})(e^{t^2/2}-1)+(t^2-1)(e^{-t^2/2})\int_0^te^{s^2/2}ds$$

$$y''_2(t)=te^{-t^2/2}+(-t+te^{-t^2/2})+(t^2-1)(e^{-t^2/2})\int_0^te^{s^2/2}ds$$

$$y''+ty'+y=0$$
$$[te^{-t^2/2}+(-t+te^{-t^2/2})+(t^2-1)(e^{-t^2/2})\int_0^te^{s^2/2}ds]+t[1-e^{-t^2/2}+(-te^{-t^2/2})\int_0^te^{s^2/2}ds]+[e^{-t^2/2}\int_0^te^{s^2/2}ds]$$
$$te^{-t^2/2}+(-t+te^{-t^2/2})+(t^2-1)(e^{-t^2/2})\int_0^te^{s^2/2}ds+t-te^{-t^2/2}+t(-te^{-t^2/2})\int_0^te^{s^2/2}ds+e^{-t^2/2}\int_0^te^{s^2/2}ds$$
$$=te^{-t^2/2}$$ But it is supposed to equal 0

If you could point out my calculation error or mistake in technique I'd appreciate it.

Comment: **Hint:** What is $d/dt \left( \int_0^te^{s^2/2}ds\right)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice this

$$ \left( \int_0^te^{s^2/2}ds\right)' = e^{t^2/2} $$

not

$$ \left( \int_0^te^{s^2/2}ds\right)'=e^{t^2/2} - 1 $$

**Note:**

> $$ \frac{d}{dt}\int_{a}^{t} f(u)du  = f(t).$$

Comment: Oh right! I was making the mistake of $e^{t^2/2}-e^{0^2/2}$ when it should have been $e^{t^2-0^2/2}$ right?

Comment: @MathMajor: Do not worry it happens with all of us! Good job.

Comment: @MathMajor: I already gave you the correct answer! Not what is in your comment.

Answer (score 0):

the $y$ defined by $$ye^{t^2/2} = \int_0^t e^{s^2/2} \, ds \tag 1$$ 
satisfies the differential equation  $$y'' + 2ty' + (1+t^2)y = 2t. \tag 2$$

differentiating $(1)$ you get $$y'e^{t^2/2} + tye^{t^2/2} =e^{t^2/2} .\tag 3 $$

differentiating $(3)$ you get $$y''e^{t^2/2} + 2ty'e^{t^2/2} + y\left(e^{t^2/2} + t^2e^{t^2/2}\right)  =te^{t^2/2} $$ clearing $e^{t^2/2}$ gives you $(2).$